# Is there any equivalence of __DIR__ in Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In many script files, __DIR__ means the directory where the script file itself is located.

Is there any equivalence in GNU Make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `CURDIR` variable. See [here](http://www.makelinux.net/make3/make3-CHP-3-SECT-8.html). `CURDIR` contains the current working, and was introduced in GNU make 3.77. With older versions of gnu make, you may need to use ${PWD}.